Getting random public key/address from cloudHSM signature in Nodejs
Generating key pair -
var publicKeyTemplate = [
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_PUBLIC_KEY },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN, value: true },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL, value: "My EC Public Key 1" },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_EC_PARAMS, value: Buffer.from("06052b8104000a", "hex") },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_VERIFY, value: true },
];

var privateKeyTemplate = [
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_CLASS, value: pkcs11js.CKO_PRIVATE_KEY },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_TOKEN, value: true },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_LABEL, value: "My EC Private Key 1" },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_DERIVE, value: true },
    { type: pkcs11js.CKA_SIGN, value: true },
];
        
var keys = pkcs11.C_GenerateKeyPair(session, { mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_EC_KEY_PAIR_GEN }, publicKeyTemplate, privateKeyTemplate);

Generating signature -
const session = pkcs11.C_OpenSession(slot, pkcs11js.CKF_RW_SESSION | pkcs11js.CKF_SERIAL_SESSION);
pkcs11.C_SignInit(session, { mechanism: pkcs11js.CKM_ECDSA }, keys.privateKey);
//Serializing txn obj
const serialisedTxn = serialize(txnObj)
const keccakHashOfTxn = keccak256(serialisedTxn)
const dataHash = Buffer.from(arrayify(keccakHashOfTxn))
const MAX_SIGNATURE_LENGTH = 256;  // Define your maximum signature length
let signature = Buffer.alloc(MAX_SIGNATURE_LENGTH);  // Allocate a buffer with the specified length
let signature1 = pkcs11.C_Sign(session, dataHash, signature);
console.log("Sig: ", signature1);

Signature recovery -
// sigInHex - signature buffer(in hex) from Generating signature code 
async function calculateVRS(sigInHex){
    //Put the signature received in hex
    sigInHex = sigInHex.toString();
    const signature = utils.fromRpcSig(`0x${sigInHex}`);

    return signature;
}

// msgInBuffer is the messaged that we signed
// sig is the from calculateVRS function
async function recoverSignature(msgInBuffer, sig){
    //Recovering sig
    console.log("Length of buffer: ", msgInBuffer.length)
    var pub = utils.ecrecover(msgInBuffer, sig.v, sig.r, sig.s);
    var recoveredAddress = '0x' + utils.pubToAddress(pub).toString('hex')
    console.log("recoevered address: ", recoveredAddress)
    return;
}




Recovered address is different even if I am signing with the same key.
